# Выражение "Ничего себе!"

Tags: этимология

И еще одно устойчивое выражение интересует, а именно — "ничего себе" в значении "вот это да!". Если вдуматься: "ничего — себе (не взял, не оставил)". Почему же это оборот означает сейчас выражение удивления пополам с восторгом?

Comment: @ М_Г, у меня прежний вопрос: зачем подняли давний вопрос ? Он Вам интересен или Вы взялись править  все подряд с самого начала? Это не вносит путаницу? Этого  rurouni  уже и на сайте-то давно нет, некому принять ответ, а люди сейчас начнут отвечать...

Comment: @Людмила Я навожу порядок и красоту не для автора, который  давно забыл сюда дорогу, а для новых читателей, которые, как мне кажется, просматривают старые вопросы в поисках ответа на интересующие их темы.

Comment: Вне зависимости от нашей воли Community все время ставит старые вопросы в начало списка. Так что дополнительной путаницы я вроде как не вношу.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то всегда это было с нейтральным или отрицательным значением: Ничего себе (разг.) 1) Так себе, сносно,не совсем  плохо, довольно хорошо Вещь получилась ничего себе; 2) выражение иронического отношения, недоверия, неодобрения. Ничего себе отличник! (т. е. вовсе не отличник).
А вообще-то значение  соединившихся разговорных частиц такое:

НИЧЕГО́ (разг.).
1. нареч. Довольно хорошо, сносно. Чувствует себя ничего. Он очень даже ничего. (совсем неплох). 
2. в знач. частицы. Выражение согласия, принятия, допущения, а также оценки чего-н. как несущественного. Пусть придёт, ничего. Тебе больно? Ничего.

СЕБЕ, частица (разг.). Относится к глаголу-сказуемому, внося значение продолжающегося свободного, независимого и как бы противопоставляемого другому действия. Сидит себе. , ничего не замечая. Иди себе.! Значения: 1) сносно, довольно хорошо. Обед был ничего себе; 2) выражение иронического отношения, недоверия,неодобрения. Опять поругались. - Ничего себе! 3) ни плохо ни хорошо, средне. Фильм этот - так себе; 2) о ком-чем-н. неважном, весьма посредственном. Помощник он так себе. Пускай (пусть) себе (разг.) -выражение принятия, согласия с оттенком безразличия, незаинтересованности.Он настаивает на своем. - Пускай себе.

В современном языке появилось значение оценочной характеристики чего-либо как вызывающего удивление, восхищение и т.п., как и "ни фига себе" и тому подобные просторечия. Есть мнение, что слово материально и  такие слова несут вред организму, программируя отрицательным словом"ничего" отрицательный результат: "Скажешь "ничего"- ничего и не получишь!" Лучше употреблять положительные восклицания "вот это да!" и т.п.Такие слова мы употребляем от бездумности, от бедности словаря, как Эллочка у Ильфа и Петрова.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так. Выражение "ничего себе" используется для лёгкой отрицательной оценки, как во фразе: "Подарок ничего себе / ничего так", -- где местоимение "себе", скорее, относится к объекту оценки, а не говорящему. Это, как бы, сказать "ничего плохого", чтобы не сказать "много хорошего". Это сокращается до фразы "ничего себе", которая без контекста иногда может терять сарказм и затем устойчиво выражать обычное удивление.

Answer (score 0):

Вдумываться, как это сделали вы, не следует как минимум потому, что слово "ничего" может означать не только отсутствие чего-либо, но и, например, "нормально" или "ничего плохого". Пример: "Машина ничего такая".   
В украинском языке есть слова "нічогенько", "нічогенький", означающие "неплохо", "неплохой". Оттуда, наверное, и пошло подобное выражение.

Comment: >В украинском языке есть слова "нічогенько", "нічогенький", означающие "неплохо", "неплохой". 

Означать-то оно означает, но... происходит это слово тоже от слова "нiчого", т.е. "ничего". Не получаем ли замкнутый круг? И потом "нічогенький" -- это такой всё-таки *разговорный* оборот речи. 

Скажите украинцу перевести с русс. на укр. язык слово "неплохой". Как он переведёт? Скорее всего литературным словом "непоганий".